# How to measure availability of a rest api?

Tags: rest, architecture, metrics

Under the assumption that availability for an API means that the API must return a 2xx status code for each request, how should the implementation look like?

Several solutions come to mind but I feel like all of them are flawed in some sense. Google search on this surprisingly resulted in WHAT availability is, instead of HOW to actually implement the source.

#### Solution 1:

Have the API send a metric depending upon the response code. 2xx - success and 4xx, 5xx - downtime.

While this is easy to implement, what happens when the entire server is down and is not able to entertain any requests? The code which sends the metric will never be executed.

#### Solution 2:

Have an external system monitor the responses and build a metric around that.

But what happens when the external system is in itself down? Also what if there are no users / requests? Do I still say my API is available?

In theory this external service could send dummy requests at a defined time intervals. But is that really the best solution?

#### Solution 3:

In addition to Solution 1, availability of an API first takes server heart-beats in consideration.

But even with this, it would be impossible to check for scenarios like when the API is incorrectly configured and is unable to entertain any requests.

I've a feeling that there must be a better way to design a solution around this, or is this it?

Comment: Solution 2 is the common one, and there are paid services that have multiple servers worldwide that can ping your API server at defined intervals.   With AWS you could roll your own with cheap lightsail servers in multiple regions, cron jobs.

Comment: You'd want to use a user account / token that has severely restricted rights, that is it only has the right to make the health check API call and nothing else.  Or that one API call could not require any rights.  Don't give out normal access to third parties or put them on servers that don't need the rights.

Comment: To abstract out the problem a little, would it be safe to say that the best approach to measure availability of a service is to observe it from an external system?

Comment: Yes, and the paid services can also automatically send your staff email notifications of services being offline and later back in service, tracking outage lengths.  You should check the cost for using a paid service before spending the time and effort to create your own.  But actually we do both with our Amazon services -- AWS has tools for health checks and replacing dying servers, plus we have the external service which tells us when AWS itself is having issues (rare, but it happens).  Azure and Google probably have health check services too.